# Likelihood for a three level linear mixed effect model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, likelihood

Consider the therapist data described in https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer. We have patients ($j$) clustered with respect to therapists (i).
Let $u_{0ij} $ be patient-specific random intercept and $v_{0i} $ be therapist specific random intercept such that:

$u_{0ij} \sim \mathcal{N}( 0, \tau_u^2) \text{ and& } v_{0i} \sim \mathcal{N}( 0, \tau_v^2)$
and

$\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N} (0, \tau_\varepsilon^2 )$

The three level random intercept model is: $y_{ij}= b_0 +u_{0ij}+v_{0i}+ b_1 \text{time} + \varepsilon$

To fit this linear mixed effect model I used the `lmer()` function (`lme4` package) in R as follows:

```
lmer(y ~ time + (1 | subjects)+ (1|therapist), data=data)
```

Theoretically:

1. How will the marginal loglikelihood function fitted by REML look like?
2. What will be $\mathbb{E}\left( u_{0j}| y_{ij} \right ) \text{ and } \mathbb{E}\left( v_{0i}| y_{ij} \right )$